# is it possible to use a console application as a pass-through for a selenium webscraper to grab a value and pass it back to a main program?

Tags: c#, selenium

Just started looking into this tonight. I'm looking to use a webscraper (I saw selenium as a viable option) and got it working to retrieving a value for me from a page. However, I want to be able to call this program as if it were a function within a Windows Forms app, passing in string values (to create a unique URL on each call) and then have the console application give me back the value I want from the page. Is this possible or a round-about way of doing things? Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: C# has good selenium libs, so that would be a better way than shelling out to python for example.